# When inserting new record in existing table tt goes up instead of down

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have already created table I want to add extra row when adding extra row the created extra row goes up. I want that row at the bottom.

```
MariaDB [armydetails]> insert into armydetails values('r05','Shishir','Bhujel','Jhapa','9845678954','male','1978-6-7','1994-1-3','ran5','Na11088905433');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)

MariaDB [armydetails]> select * from armydetails;
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+
| regNo | fName   | lName   | address   | number     | gender | DOB        | DOJ        | rankID | accountNo      |
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+
| r05   | Shishir | Bhujel  | Jhapa     | 9845678954 | male   | 1978-06-07 | 1994-01-03 | ran5   | Na11088905433  |
| ro1   | Milan   | Katwal  | Dharan    | 9811095122 | Male   | 1970-01-03 | 1990-01-01 | ran1   | Na11984567823  |
| ro2   | Hari    | Yadav   | Kathmandu | 9810756436 | male   | 1980-06-07 | 2000-05-06 | ran2   | Na119876678543 |
| ro3   | Khrisna | Neupane | Itahari   | 9864578934 | male   | 1980-02-02 | 2001-01-07 | ran3   | Na11954437890  |
| ro4   | Lalit   | Rai     | Damak     | 9842376547 | male   | 1989-05-09 | 2005-01-02 | ran4   | Na11064553221  |
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [armydetails]>
```

Comment: Table records are *unordered*... Unless you use `ORDER BY`. See [this famouse Tom Kyte blog post](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/order-in-court.html)

Comment: But in some table it is order how

Comment: If every insert is new and should be following a running number, I suggest you add another column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` field

Comment: by look of it, other records have 'ro1...ro4' (the alphabet) whereas first row inserted has 'r05' (0 - number zero). Perhaps you are expecting and will see it to be at bottom, when you insert 'ro5'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an ORDER BY clause to your statment as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM armydetails ORDER BY regNO DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [SQL 2011 publication from ISO/IEC 9075](http://www.jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2151-2200/32N2153T-text_for_ballot-FDIS_9075-1.pdf) says:

> In general, rows in a table are unordered; however, rows in a table are ordered if the table is the result of a  that immediately contains an « order by clause ».

In a SQL database, there is no underlying, default ordering for records. A relational database basically stores a table as a bunch of unordered records.

When records are `SELECT`ed without an `ORDER BY` clause, they come out in an undefined order, that in no way is guaranteed to be consistent over subsequent queries (including the very same query being executed several times). This is true for MySQL *and* for other RDBMS.

The only way to properly order records is to use an `ORDER BY` clause, like:

```
select * from armydetails order by regNo
```

Suggested lecture: [Tom Kyte Blog : Order in the Court!](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/order-in-court.html).